# "Recover" Windows 8.1 after switching to Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, recovery-disk

I have a couple of laptops with Windows 8.1. I'd like to make one of them a Linux machine. I'm debating different ways to go.

I know I can use a live CD, create multiple boot-able partitions, or use VirtualBox to try and have the best of both worlds. I've been wondering, though, if I just want to remove Windows completely from one of the machines and make it a dedicated Linux machine, if it would then be possible to "recover" or "restore" Windows on that machine later with a recovery disk.

In other words, say I make a recovery disk for Windows 8.1 from machine A, then I install CentOS. Would I still be able to get Windows 8.1 back from the recovery disk on machine A, or would the fact that Windows wasn't there anymore make the recovery disk useless?

Comment: A Windows Recovery Disk cannot install Windows its only used to repair Windows.  If you want to install Windows tha would require an installation disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to make a Windows Backup to an external medium. (USB drive)
And create a "recovery disk/system repair disk" with that same Windows Backup tool.

That should give you the option to boot from the recovery disk and restore the backup from there.

**Before you wipe the harddisk: TEST** it up to the point of starting the actual restore process. This should indicate whether or not this entire scenario will work.
(I've seen some recovery disks that wouldn't boot, or didn't contain the drivers for the USB3 controller.)
Even better: If you've got a spare HD around temporarily place it in the system and do a real restore on that. (Of course, if you have a disk to spare you could just install Linux on that.)

A fresh re-install of Windows 8 isn't too difficult either as long as you have an install medium (ISO's are pretty easy to find online or borrow an install DVD from a friend).
If the computer has a baked-in license-key in the UEFI bios that fresh install will automatically find and use the key.
If it isn't baked-in you should have the label with the key somewhere on the PC. (A Win8 key will also work with 8.1)